# Change Single Button Color from ngRepeat generated button list

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using ngRepeat to generate four buttons. Whenever I click one of the buttons, I want to change its color and also execute a function (for now, I'm just using console.log for sake of simplicity). If I click on another button, I want to change its color while reverting the previous button back to its original color.

I have a couple of issues - the first is that I can't seem to get ng-click to accept two commands (the first being the console.log function and the second being the instruction to change the button color). The other issue is that if I take out the console.log function, I end up changing all of the buttons when I click on one.

Any ideas? Here's the plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/x1yLEGNOcBNfVw2BhbWA. You'll see the console.log works but the button changing doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong with this ng-click?

```
<span class="btn cal-btn btn-default" ng-class="{'activeButton':selectedButt === 'me'}" ng-click="log(element);selectedButt = 'me'" data-ng-repeat="element in array">{{element}}</span>
```

Comment: Oh god...the ng-click works in the plunkr and executes both the console.log and the color change. Now I need to figure out why it's not working. However, I could still use some help figuring out how to change the changed button to its original color when another button is clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a simple function in your controller which handles this logic:

```
$scope.selectButton = function(index) {
    $scope.activeBtn = index;
}
```

Then, you can simply check in your template if the current button is active:

```
<span class="btn cal-btn btn-default" ng-class="{true:'activeButton'}[activeBtn == $index]" ng-click="selectButton($index);" ng-repeat="element in array">{{element}}</span>
```

I also changed your [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2rEPqQhoAhheLeUNT7Gb?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You may convert your element list from string array to object array first.

```
$scope.array = [
  {"name":"first", "checked":false},
  {"name":"second", "checked":false},
  {"name":"third", "checked":false},
  {"name":"fourth", "checked":false}
];
```

And your log function need to change to:

```
$scope.log = function(element) {
  console.log(element.name);

  angular.forEach($scope.array, function(elem) {
    elem.checked = false;
  });

  element.checked = !element.checked;
}
```

Then, in your HTML:

```
<button class="btn cal-btn"
  ng-repeat="element in array"
  ng-click="log(element)"
  ng-class="{activeButton: element.checked, 'btn-default': !element.checked}"
  >{{element.name}}</button>
```

Please see the updated plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/UFFVBAtcHqrJzhvKjcLv?p=preview).